# Change specific values with mean based on neighbors

Tags: r

I have dataset with values from 100 to 200, but there are a few spikes in data.
I don't want to smooth the whole dataset with rollmean or rollaplly.

I want to work it in that way:

1. find these spikes with condition (value > 300)
2. replace these too big values with mean/median that had been
   calculated from 10 near neighbors values.

Example in pseudo-code:

```
data[n] = spike

data[n] = mean(from data[n-5] to data[n+5])
```

It's like using window function not on the whole data set, only on certain points in data.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Please add a reproducible example. What do you mean 'from 10 near neighbors'?

Comment: what happens if you have 2 'spikes' one after another? or If the `n+5` `n-5` have spikes?- Please have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: median with enough window size should solve this

Comment: Thank you for the link, I will add a reproducible example as soon as i get to my laptop with R and Data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like this question. A typical moving average/k-nearest neighbourhood estimation. A nonnparametric approach. The following should work.

```
foo <- function(x, thresh = 300, h = 5, window.fun = mean) {
  spikes.loc <- which(x > thresh)
  low.bound <- spikes - h
  up.bound <- spikes + h
  N <- length(spikes.loc)
  x.hat <- x
  for (i in 1:N) x.hat[spikes.loc[i]] <- window.fun(x[low.bound[i]:up.bound[i]])
  return(x.hat)
  }
```

This function takes your original observations vector `x`, threshold, a window size (a smoothing parameter) as well as a user-specified window function. The returned value is the vector smoothed data. It only differs from original data at spikes points. Common choice of a window function is density function, so you end up with weighted average of all neighbouring data.

Please note, I am assuming your data are evenly spaced, so a simple index x[i-h] : x[i+h] gives a reasonable neighbourhood. In more general setting, a window is based on euclidean distance, but will naively costs O(N*N), where N is the number of observations, which is expensive.

In R, there are built-in nonparametric estimation / smoothing tools. The most basic one is `kernel smoothing`, a generalization of moving average. It uses FFT algorithm for fast computation at O(N log(N)) costs. Please see `?ksmooth`. More advanced are `KernSmooth` and `sm` packages.

Comment: thanks, looks like i want. I thought about handwritten function, but decided to ask first before inventing the wheel.